# Galleria jquery plugin not working on ASP.net MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, galleria

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with this, but I can't find anything that is wrong, I'm 100% sure everything is setup correctly, but the plugin is still not working.
The name of the jquery plugin I am trying to use is 'Galleria' their website can be found on
[this](http://galleria.aino.se/) link.

To view my website and look at the error message, click on [this](http://www.henrynorthen.com) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing this file or referencing it wrong:

```
http://www.henrynorthen.com/Scripts/galleria.classic.css
```

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="<% =Url.Content("~/scripts/galleria.classic.css") %>" />
```

Comment: I added it, then it gave a different error, then I fixed that different error now it is working :O
I'm sure I already tried putting that .css file in the code... Oh well, thanks =)